# How to change the y axis text in R?

Tags: r, axis-labels

I'm trying to customise the y axis text in a geom_bar plot from the default 0-200 to 0-7..

Everything I have tried so far is not working.. Can anybody advise #VeryNewToR This is my code so far:

```
g2 <- ggplot(data = Aug_13, aes(x = Care_Status, y = Avo_Avg)) +xlab(NULL)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.4) + ggtitle("Avoidance") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm"))
  expand_limits(y=c(0, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do **+ ylab( )** For instance;

```r
g2 + ylab("New Label Name")
```